# MySQL or PHP date averages

Tags: php, mysql, time, average

I am trying to figure out how to find the average of a number of different time values, the time values are time differences from 2 dates so they will be in the format of `hh:mm:ss`.
So if I had 4 time values of:

> 00:11:05
>   00:01:30
>   00:04:25
>   00:09:50

I have trouble figuring this out.
I think these time values would need to be converted to some type of integer value then divided then converted back to this time format.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What datatype are these?

Comment: hh:mm:ss can only represent time, not date, I am afraid. You can convert them to seconds then average. i.e., 1 hour = 60 min = 3600sec. etc... then convert back if needed

Comment: I am trying to find the average of the time values.  And the data type is whatever is returned from doing a DATEDIFF.  So each one of those time values from above is a result of doing DATEDIFF on 2 different dates.

Comment: I'm sorry...I meant TIMEDIFF and NOT DATEDIFF

Comment: Martin, seems like you deleted your answer or its not showing up but it works great...thanks.

Comment: @Ian I deleted it because sometimes it seemed to return `NULL` on my test data and I wasn't sure why! I can see Wrikken also gave the same answer and then deleted it. @Wrikken - did you find the same issue?

Comment: @Martin: if you mean just running `AVG` over timefields: I thought it would work, but actually it casts it quite stupidly to integer, and the averages don't work out. I.e.: `cast(avg('01:30','2:30') as time))` results in NULL (01:80 is invalid), `cast(avg('01:10','2:00') as time)` results in 01:55, when it should be 01:35, see the pattern? It will just sum 110 + 200 = 310, 310/2 = 155, cast as time = 01:55. Not what we're looking for :(

Comment: @Wrikken - Right that would explain the `NULL`s I was getting. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I am seeing the problem with the NULL values now.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(
    FROM_UNIXTIME(
         AVG(
              UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT('1980-01-01 ',timefield))
         )
    ),
    '%H:%i:%s.%f') FROM times;
```